# On a mac can I use CUPS to set a minimum font size?

Tags: macos, fonts, printing, cups, accessibility

I am setting up a mac for an aunt who needs large fonts to read, I have set up Safari correctly but there is a problem.

When I print the text comes out at the original font size, not the enlarged size displayed.

Is there any way to configure CUPS so that if it ever spots a font below 18it will increase the font size to 18

Comment: Unlikely.  But you shouldn't specify what software you want to use to solve your problem:  instead, state what OS you're running on, and allow _us_ to suggest the software you should use.  Voted -1.

Comment: Try Mozilla Firefox's minimum-font-size feature.  Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

No. CUPS is not responsible for the content, merely for shuffling the print data around. Configure the application to require using a minimum font size when printing.